# Web automation IFrame trouble

Tags: vba, iframe, automation

I'm currently working as a temp in the HR department of a major hospital.  In order to convince the powers that be of the need to upgrade from the "trial version" to the "salary + benefits" subscription model of my employment contract I've decided to take on a bit of a project.

The excel spreadsheet will log into a vendor website and download a report with a list of employees currently out on sick leave, then it will log into the website of our insurance company and pull information on STD claims for use by payroll (this is currently done manually by a 70 yr old lady who types at 30 WPM..... and no, she does not even use basic copy and paste).

Everything works just fine up until the point where I click the button to download the report.  I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax to download the spreadsheet.  Switching to chrome and using Selenium isn't an option, due to our IT departments blinding levels of bureaucracy.

Here is the code I have so far.  Office 16.0 office library, HTML object library, and microsoft internet controls are included in references.

Module 1

```
Option Private Module
Public Function OpenReport(doc As HTMLDocument) As Long
On Error GoTo Failed
doc.getElementsByClassName("k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-view")(3).Click
OpenReport = 1
Done:
Exit Function
Failed:
OpenReport = 0
End Function
```

Module 2

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim i As Long
Dim rWin As HTMLDivElement

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://leavexpert.com/"

Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set doc = IE.document

'inputs a username and password then clicks the login button
doc.getElementById("UserName").Value = "*****"
doc.getElementById("Password").Value = "*****"
doc.getElementsByClassName("validateAndSubmit k-button")(0).Click

Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

'having the program wait while IE.busy does not seem to work, so wrapping the button click in it's 
'own function and using error handling to return a 1 or 0 on success or failure is my creative work 
'around
IE.navigate "https://leavexpert.com/Reports"
i = 0
Do While i = 0
    i = OpenReport(doc)
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set rWin = doc.getElementsByClassName("k-widget k-window")(0)

'this gives me some output which tells me im on the right track.
Debug.Print rWin.className
Debug.Print rWin.innerHTML
```

Debug output

```
k-widget k-window k-state-focused
<div class="k-window-titlebar k-header" style="margin-top: -27px;">&nbsp;<span class="k-window-title" 
id="reportWindow_wnd_title">Case Detail</span><div class="k-window-actions"><a class="k-window-action 
k-link" role="button" href="#"><span class="k-icon k-i-maximize" role="presentation">Maximize</span> 
</a><a class="k-window-action k-link" role="button" href="#"><span class="k-icon k-i-close" 
role="presentation">Close</span></a></div></div><div tabindex="0" class="k-window-content k-content 
k-window-iframecontent" id="reportWindow" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="reportWindow_wnd_title" 
data-role="window"><div class="k-loading-mask" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 
100%;"><span class="k-loading-text">Loading...</span><div class="k-loading-image"></div><div 
class="k-loading-color"></div></div><iframe title="Case Detail" class="k-content-frame" 
src="/Areas/Reports/ReportViewer.aspx?reportId=1005" frameborder="0">This page requires frames in 
order to show content</iframe></div><div class="k-resiz
e-handle k-resize-n"></div><div class="k-resize-handle k-resize-e"></div><div class="k-resize-handle 
k-resize-s"></div><div class="k-resize-handle k-resize-w"></div><div class="k-resize-handle k-resize- 
se"></div><div class="k-resize-handle k-resize-sw"></div><div class="k-resize-handle k-resize-ne"> 
</div><div class="k-resize-handle k-resize-nw"></div>
```

A screenshot of the HTML of the element i need to click to download.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGDfn.jpg)

UPDATE:  Slow day, so I've got downtime to do some testing.

Here is some updated code at the end of my sub

```
    Do While i = 0
        i = OpenReport(doc)
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    
    Set doc = IE.document
    
    'New stuff starts here, I'll move the declarations once I have it 
    'working.
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 30, Now)
    
    Set doc = IE.document
    Dim rWin As HTMLDivElement
    Set rWin = doc.getElementsByClassName("k-widget k-window")(0)
    
    
    For i = 0 To 11
        Debug.Print rWin.getElementsByTagName("div")(i).innerText
    Next
    
    
End Sub
```

New debug output.

```
 Case Detail
MaximizeClose
MaximizeClose
This page requires frames in order to show content
```

[Iframe screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOADk.jpg)

Comment: You call `IE.navigate "https://leavexpert.com/Reports"` but then you don't re-call `Set doc = IE.document` after that navigation event.  You need to do that, or `doc` is still pointing at the previous page. Also, from the screenshot you can see what script is triggered by the excel selection, so you can call that directly using  `doc.parentWindow.execScript "[onclick js from screen shot here]", "jscript"`

Comment: doc.parentWindow.execScript "[onclick = '$find('ReportViewer1').exportReport('EXCELOPENXML');']"

Thats throwing an error.  Where did a screw up the syntax?

Comment: `doc.parentWindow.execScript "$find('ReportViewer1').exportReport('EXCELOPENXML');", "jscript"`

Comment: ...but make sure you have the correct `doc` reference

Comment: Run-time error '-2147352319 (80020101)
Automation error

Should i be trying to execute the script from the child window?

Comment: My last guess: `IE.document.parentWindow.execScript "$find('ReportViewer1').exportReport('EXCELOPENXML');", "jscript"`  But you need to make sure you wait for the navigation event to complete.

Comment: `ie.document.querySelector("a[title=Excel][onclick*=EXCELOPENXML]").click`

Comment: IE.document.parentWindow.execScript "$find('ReportViewer1').exportReport('EXCELOPENXML');", "jscript"

Gives could not complete due to error 80020101.  Anyone got anymore ideas?

Comment: IE.document.querySelector("a[title=Excel][onclick*=EXCELOPENXML]").Click

Object required error.  I feel like I'm missing something basic.

Comment: "could not complete due to error 80020101" is coming from the browser, or from VBA?

Comment: the error is coming from VBA

Comment: my querySelector would fail either due to timing or if element inside frame/iframe. It didn't look like an iframe was actually involved given the image provided. Have you confirmed it is definitely inside an iframe?

Comment: 100% Confirmed it's inside of an IFrame.  I didn't know IFrames even existed before today........  Now I'm convinced there is a special layer of #311 reserved for whoever came up with the idea for them........

Comment: what the html of the iframe opening tag?  Does it have an src attribute? And is this iframe nested within another?

Comment: check the bottom of the main post for a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT WORKS!!!!! IT WORKS!!!!! IT WORKS!!!!  I had to set IE to always allow popups from this website, but after that.........  IT WORKED!!!!!!!!!!!!  Now to figure out how to handle the open/save box.

```
'standard declarations
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim i As Long
Dim iWin As HTMLIFrame

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://leavexpert.com/"

Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set doc = IE.document

'This part puts in the login details and clicks the login button
doc.getElementById("UserName").Value = "*******"
doc.getElementById("Password").Value = "*******"
doc.getElementsByClassName("validateAndSubmit k-button")(0).Click

'wait for the website to finish loading
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

'Go to the report section of the website
IE.navigate "https://leavexpert.com/Reports"
Set doc = IE.document


'Having the program wait while IE.busy does not seem to work, so wrapping the button click in it's own function
'and using error handling to return a 1 or 0 on success or failure is my creative work around
i = 0
Do While i = 0
    i = OpenReport(doc)
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

'Not quite sure if i need to set the doc variable here or not.  I read somewhere that you need to do it every time you change webpages.
'Don't know if opening a child window counts, but better safe than sorry.
Set doc = IE.document

'Set the iWin object to the report window.
Set iWin = doc.getElementsByClassName("k-content-frame")(0)

'Wait for the report to finish loading.  I know the program is looking at the correct object, because the debug printouts match when the window
'finishes loading.
Do While iWin.readyState <> "complete"
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)

'This is the line that clicks the button!!!!!
iWin.contentDocument.querySelector("a[title=Excel][onclick*=EXCELOPENXML]").Click
```